# problemas con mi busqueda mediante input... si lo busco por numero de order si lo encuentro pero si no busco por su nombre de cliente no lo encuentra

Tags: nodejs, ts, prisma

problemas con mi busqueda mediante input... si lo busco por numero de order si lo encuentro pero si no busco por su nombre de cliente no lo encuentra

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código es siempre como texto,  Y ese código debe ser una porción que podamos ejecutar sin mayor problema y que a su vez sea mínima, sin ruido de otras funcionalidades que no importan al problema en cuestión.